# Getting 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' in browser when trying to access Wordpress website with Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, redirect, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to deploy a simple Wordpress website with Nginx as reverse proxy but right after I installed SSl (Let's Encrypto Certbot), I can no longer access the default wordpress install page, instead I'm getting browser's 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'.

The Nginx config is set up to redirect all traffic from http to https and also from non-www to www.

Here's how the config file looks like:

```
upstream site1-php-handler {
        server unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
}

server {

        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {

        root /var/www/html/example.com;
        server_name www.example.com;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass site1-php-handler;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example_error.log;


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I’m unclear on the purpose of the `if` statement is for. The `server_name` directive guarantees it will be that name, but then you have a redirect to the same name

Comment: @ChrisHaas Those are added by Certbot. If I remove those, then I dont get ERR Too many redirects. But I get 404 nginx error,

Comment: Use: `curl -I https://www.example.com/` to identify the response from your server.